# what is the recommended approach for application settings in RoR?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i'm a .net guy doing some work/learning RoR. i have a handful of environment-specific settings i'd like to externalize (s3 access info). what is the way to do this? I realize the place for it is in config/environment/[environment], but i'm asking beyond that. Should it be a global constant? should i use an initializer? how do i cleanly make this data available to the consuming class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Putting the environment config in the environment files is considered the best practice. You can define these configs as constants and they will be available everywhere in your application automatically.

```
S3Config = { :username => "blah" }
```

Access the `:user` key by calling `S3Config[:user]`.

Comment: does the contents of those environment files get imported into the runtime by default? my first approach was to just define two constants in /development, but i needed a $ when consuming them (yes, i'm a ruby n00b)

Comment: The key is :username, not :user.

Comment: kolosy: You don't need a global constant (a variable beginning with `$`) just capitalize the first letter (yes, it **has** to be a letter) of the variable and that will define it as a constant. The rest of the letters don't need to be capitalized.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [SimpleConfig Gem](http://github.com/lukeredpath/simpleconfig). It allows you to define environment variables.

It also supports environment priorities so that you can define base variables in the application.rb configuration file and override them in your environment-specific configuration files.